# Gradle wrapper times out when using a proxy

Tags: gradle, proxy, gradle-wrapper

This question is specifically about the **Gradle wrapper** and not a full Gradle installation.

My company forces me to use a proxy to access many urls, and all it usually takes to fix timeout problems is to configure whatever is trying to access said urls to use the proxy, after which I get a certificate verification error and I have to also add the sites' SSL certificates to Java's keystore (take [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36427118/3514976) as an example for how to do the latter).

With the Gradle wrapper (version 7.4.1+), though, I'm still getting a timeout.
I searched, and I found many people appearing to have this problem. Most of them though, simply had to configure the proxy in the `gradle.properties` file (on Windows it's by default in `%userprofile%\.gradle`):

```
systemProp.http.proxyHost=the proxy host
systemProp.http.proxyPort=the port
systemProp.http.proxyUser=username (if authentication is needed)
systemProp.http.proxyPassword=password (if authentication is needed)
systemProp.https.proxyHost=the proxy host
systemProp.https.proxyPort=the port
systemProp.https.proxyUser=username (if authentication is needed)
systemProp.https.proxyPassword=password (if authentication is needed)
```

Or, they had to remove a wrong proxy configuration from the file.
A few of them solved the problem by increasing Gradle's timeouts with these properties:

```
systemProp.org.gradle.internal.http.connectionTimeout=300000
systemProp.org.gradle.internal.http.socketTimeout=300000
```

These solutions aren't working for me. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the cause to be an hardcoded connection timeout value in the sources of the `gradle-wrapper`. [See this issue in their Github](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/17575); it seems they're gonna fix it for version 7.6.

The `org.gradle.internal.http.connectionTimeout` and `org.gradle.internal.http.socketTimeout` system properties mentioned in the question are only taken into account by Gradle "proper", not by the wrapper.

So, setting longer timeout wait times in the `gradle.properties` file doesn't work. How to solve the issue without manually downloading stuff from the Gradle site?
One way would be to recompile the wrapper from the sources after changing the timeouts. Another easier solution though is to edit the compiled jar. You can use something like [Recaf](https://github.com/Col-E/Recaf) for that.

[image: change the pesky timeouts]

Then you replace the `gradle-wrapper.jar` you were using and try again.

Once the wrapper manages to download the "dist" the first time, you might not run into this problem anymore even with the original jar.

If you do get a timeout again after that first time, then this is what you have to do to make sure that the modified `gradle-wrapper.jar` is used instead of the original, for example by IDEs when creating new projects:

- go to `%userprofile%\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-<version>-bin\<folder with a random-looking name>\gradle-<version>\lib`
  For example in my case it was:
  `C:\Users\username\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-7.4.2-bin\48ivgl02cpt2ed3fh9dbalvx8\gradle-7.4.2\lib`
- open the `gradle-wrapper-<version>.jar` file
- replace the `gradle-wrapper.jar` that's inside it with the modified one.

Yes, it's a jar containing another similarly-named jar. **Don't** replace the outer one with your modified jar.

[image]

Comment: This is indeed fixed in Gradle 7.6 and newer. More details about the fix: https://github.com/gradle/gradle/pull/20504. Release notes are here: https://docs.gradle.org/7.6/release-notes.html